# Java validation framework @Pattern reg exp based validation for excluding the apostrophe('),slash(\) and double quotes(")

Tags: java, spring

I am working on spring mvc based web application and i am using annotation based form validation framework to validate the form.

Here i got a requirement like to exclude apostrophe('),slash() and double quotes(").

I tried with the below.Not worked

```
@Pattern(regexp="^!?[\'\\\\\"]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a character class:

```
@Pattern(regex="[^\'\\\"]")
```